# How important is relevant research for an undergrad?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate

I'm a student in electrical engineering, and my interests lie primarily in areas with a large overlap between physics and electrical engineering. I'm currently doing research with a professor of computer engineering, doing computer engineering research, which doesn't exactly line up with my interests, but it is research experience.

Now, when I'm applying for graduate schools, I believe I'll have to write a statement of purpose. How does it affect my chances of getting into graduate schools if I write about how I want to do research in [certain area of EE], but the school sees that all of my actual *research* experience is in an entirely different branch of electrical engineering?

Or in other words--do graduate admissions committees care about what field I do my undergrad research in, or do they only care that I do research in general?

Comment: I would argue that my question differs in that the aforementioned question is asking about research experience in an entirely different field (economics vs statistics) whereas mine focuses on what are considered two subsets of one field.

Comment: All of the answers there describe a continuum, from two very closely related fields (like your situation) to two less closely related fields (the OP's situation there) to two unrelated fields ("If you were majoring in philosophy and wanted to pursue a Ph.D. in chemistry"). As far as I can tell, the answers there apply equally to this question.